# Javascript Date object failing

Tags: javascript

On just one page of my site the javascript Date object won't work.  Calling `Date.parse(dateString)` or `new Date(dateString)` returns `undefined` instead of the expected Date object.  In fact on this page, typing this command into the firebug console will crash the entire browser (this command being something like `Date.parse("6/1/2013")` or `Date.parse("Jun 6, 2013")` ).  This only happens on this one page and these same commands work just fine in every other page.  I've looked for anywhere that the Date object and functions might have been overwritten but couldn't find anything.  Does anyone know what might be causing this error?

Comment: what does `alert(Date);` show you?

Comment: Do you get any error on the page where it doesn't work?

Comment: the only thing I can think of is that maybe you included a js library which also includes a date object, and that object doesn't have a parse method. Try getting rid of all of the script references that you don't absolutely need and see if that fixes the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - does this happen in any browser? or is it specific to one?

The most likely scenario is that you have some plug-in (Java applet, Flash, Silverlite or something else entirely) on that one page which overwrites the built-in Javascript Date type with something else.

I would start looking at what is different on that page from the other pages in terms of plugins loaded and other .js files that are loaded only on that page and not on the others.

Comment: yeah that was the problem one of the plugins that is being loaded for this page is messing things up thanks

Answer (score 0):

Date objects are pretty flexible, they are more apt to return NaN from bad input than undefined. Sounds like you redefined Date- you don't have an expression that has 'Date='anywhere, do you?